# how to re-mount a home directory of a specific user to a partition

Tags: mount, users, home

My system is Ubuntu and there are three users on it. Also, I have some partitions: `/dev/sda1`, `/dev/sda2` and `/dev/sdc1`.

For now the whole `/home` directory is mounted on the `/dev/sda2`, the whole root `/` is mounted on the `/dev/sda1`.

My question is: is it possible to mount the home directory of one of the three users, such as mounting `/home/user1` on the `/dev/sdc1`? How to do it?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Do you faced any issue?

Comment: @EBINGLADSON  Yes. `/dev/sda2` is almost full, and I have some empty partitions, so I want to remount users to some other partitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make sure the user is logged out and no process uses any file in their home directory
2. Mount the sdc1 partition to some mountpoint (/mnt/sdc1 for example).
3. Move the content of user1 directory to this location.
4. Then unmount sdc1.
5. Now you can edit your `/etc/fstab` by adding a line like this:

   ```
   UUID=THE-UUID-OF-SDC1   /home/user1   FS-TYPE  defaults   0   2
   ```

   To find the UUID of your partition you can use the `blkid`command which is part of the util-linux package. This will also give you the FS-TYPE of your partition.

   ```
   blkid /dev/sdc1
   ```

After a reboot you should have /home/user1 on your sdc1 partition.

But as always by manipulating partitions and mount point, be carefull and you better have a backup of your data.